# How to show a noscript message in a body with ng-cloak

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs, noscript

In AngularJs, if your body has the "ng-cloak", how do you then show noscript messages such as "Please enable Javascript to use this service" ?

Reference: https://github.com/meanjs/mean/issues/1397